# Good Practice to check user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

The normal approach, I found online, to ensure the correct type of user input is as the code below.

```
if not isinstance(amount, int):
    raise ValueError("Please enter an integer as amount.")
else:
    return amount
```

I wrapped the above code in a function and then called the function with the parameter. I personally prefer to put it in a function. **Is it an acceptable variation to check the user input?** (in a class)

```
def __init__(self, amount):

    def check_userinput(amount):
        if not isinstance(amount, int):
            raise ValueError("Please enter an integer as amount.")
        else:
            return amount

    self.amount = check_userinput(amount)
```

Comment: Given that most *user input* will be a string anyway, `int(amount)` would accomplish pretty much the same thing…!?

Comment: maybe you can rename your function name to `is_int()` and create the corresponding function for different types.

Comment: Python programmers usually go for [duck typing](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-duck-typing) and don't even bother to check. If there's a problem, sooner or later TypeError would be thrown anyways, and if the function returns successfully, then it's a good thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user inputs will probably be `str`, not `int` unless you convert them first. To see if that's doable, the Pythonic way might be to try and see, i.e.

```
def is_int_like(x):
    try:
        int(x)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Answer (score 2):

You could go either way, community wise Python works with [EAFP principle.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python) (Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission.) I would go ahead and cast it, and just catch the exception so you can add the custom message.

In regards to your code, it would look something like:

```
try:
    self.amount = int(amount)
except ValueError as e:
    raise ValueError("Please enter an integer as amount.")
```

Answer (score 1):

User input from `input` will always be a `str`. Therefore, you can just do this:

```
def get_checked_input():
    while True:
        user_input = input('Please enter a number.')
        if user_input.isdigit():
            return user_input

        else:
            print('Something other than a number was entered.')
```